# Can ArrayList.sort modify the list before throwing an exception?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to sort an ArrayList using the Collections.sort() method.
However, my comparator does not fully respect the contract, and in some cases the sort method will throw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

My question is about the state of the list when this happens. Can it have already been modified (partially sorted)? Is it possible that it loses elements?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code of `Collections.sort` (which calls `List.sort` in Java 8), the sorting is performed on an array (using `Arrays.sort`), followed by assignment of the elements to the List in sorted order.

Therefore, any exception thrown during the sorting will prevent the List from being modified.

```
default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    Object[] a = this.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) {
        i.next();
        i.set((E) e);
    }
}
```

BTW, this is a default implementation that appears in the `List` interface. If any `List` implementation overrides this implementation with an implementation that modifies the `List` before the sorting is done, the answer to your question can change.

Comment: Beat me by a second. :) It's actually in the JavaDoc for the method, too: "This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array."

Comment: That's true, but ArrayList overrides this method and does not have the same behaviour, this is why my question is specifically about ArrayList

Comment: @yshavit In which Javadoc did you see that? The Java 8 Javadoc of Collections.sort doesn't contain this language. I only saw similar language in List.sort under a `@implSpec` tag.

Comment: Interesting, they removed it from the Java 8 docs. It's there for 7: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)

Comment: @Valette_Renoux You are correct. I just noticed myself that ArrayList overrides `sort`. It looks like the backing array of the ArrayList may be partially modified when an exception is thrown. Of course the solution would be to fix your Comparator so that it doesn't violate the contract.